# How to install PATCH UPDATE 1533 5344 .sh?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, patches

How to install PATCH UPDATE 1533 5344 .sh ??
my english is not good Please give me a simple approach in here

why can not install?

> Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh
>   script, are not installed: Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please
>   install it(them).

Answer (score 3):

So the reason for your error is that your system does not have the module "patch" installed.

This can be done via one of the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install patch
sudo yum install patch
```

Comment: sudo apt-get and sudo yum is a program?

Comment: it deppends on what type of linux system you are using, debain uses apt-get and centos uses yum to install software

Comment: the server is not me , i just have ftp and cpanel...so how to install ~thank you !!!

Comment: it might be available via cpanel otherwise you will have to email your server provider about this

Comment: my hosting told me can not ssh..so how can i do thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the two Patch Update .sh files. Make sure to get the right file for your installed version of Magento. The download location is here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/
2. Upload to your webserver or development location, into public_html or your webroot folder. So in the same folder as app and skin.
3. chmod +x *sh. For example:

   ```
   chmod +x PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh
   ```
4. run the files ./name.sh

   ```
   ./PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh
   ```
5. Remove the .sh files
6. Commit the files to version control and deploy (if needed working locally)
7. ???
8. Profit

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what is chmod +x? can you tell me? thank you?is 654?

Comment: chmod +x is a SSH/Command line command to change the permissions of the file. So that you may run the file as a executable.

Comment: ok..but where is chmod +x? how to find it..(sorry,my english is not good so if have pic show to me is good)

Comment: You need to upload the patch files to your webroot and then SSH to that location and run from there. Or apply locally and deploy your shop.

Comment: i already upload the PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh patch files to my webroot . but i dont understand where is SSH

Comment: SSH is a way of communicating with a server. If you only have FTP access you cannot run the patch's. You'll need to apply locally to your codebase. Or read the diff inside the patch and apply the patch manually.

Comment: i have FTP and Cpanel...if can not how to apply the patch manually.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you have SSH access. Or should be using it. You'll have to open the .sh files which will show you what to change/update manually

Comment: i open the sh file is this..
#!/bin/bash
# Patch apllying tool template
# v0.1.2
# (c) Copyright 2013. Magento Inc.
#
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY LINE IN THIS FILE.

# 1. Check required system tools
_check_installed_tools() {
    local missed=""

    until [ -z "$1" ]; do
        type -t $1 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        if (( $? != 0 )); then
            missed="$missed $1"
        fi
        shift
    done

    echo $missed
}

REQUIRED_UTILS='sed patch'
MISSED_REQUIRED_TOOLS=`_check_installed_tools $REQUIRED_UTILS`
if (( `ech
..................

Comment: i still not understand ..sorry...ssh??? and i open.sh files..but how to change/update manually

Comment: Yes thats correct. The actual Patch is found at __PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__ I've extracted for you: 5344 http://pastebin.com/6wPNrE2J and 1533 http://pastebin.com/UczSBuHS the lines marked - are removed and the lines marked + are added

Comment: At this point. To be frankly honest. You probably should get someone else to do this for you. Magento have tried to make this as easy as possible. Download and run the files thats it… Sure it's fiddly on Windows. But if you are running Magento on a windows server. You'd be able to read the patch files

Comment: I entered this site, is copy their source?

Comment: i can see it:...but i dont understand your mean,,,the lines marked - are removed and the lines marked + are added ????
--- app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php

Comment: Yes - is removals and + are additions. The file path -/+ are not they just tell you which file to edit

Comment: my hosting told me can not ssh..so how can i do thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can explain. The patch on the links tell you which files to edit. A - line means remove this line and replace it with the following + line

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below mentioned URL for installing a patch for MAGENTO COMMUNITY EDITION.
[installing a patch guide](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf). In this guide are very useful.

Answer (score -2):

It requires you to do put some linux code commands under PUTTY or SHH after you upload the files to the correct folder in FTP.

It's truly more than a bit complicated for new site administrators.

Comment: Well I think there was enough explanation in comments answer above yours. The question-giver didn't had any way to access his server by ssh. The explanation how to do it without ssh has been given.